# Cloudformation nested functions EC2 Image Builder

Tags: aws-cloudformation

```
Parameters:
 arn:
  Type:String
  Description: Add comp arn as comma delimited string


Resources:
Type: AWS::ImageBuilder::ImageRecipe
  Properties: 
  BlockDeviceMappings: 
    - InstanceBlockDeviceMapping
  Components: 
    - ComponentArn:"arn"
    - ComponentArn:"arn"
  Description: String
  Name: String
  ParentImage: String
  Tags: 
    Key : Value
  Version: String
```

I am trying to pass the parameter values(arn) to the ComponentArn key here in the stack. The issue is I need to take the parameter values as comma seperated string. I am not getting how to split and add it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you use [CommaDelimitedList](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) parameter type.

```
Parameters:
 arn:
  Type: CommaDelimitedList
  Description: Add comp arn as comma delimited string
```

Then you can reference individual elemnets in the list using [Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html)

Comment: Thanks Marcin appreciate your comment. But the arn parameters are dynamic , like we can input as many as we want. The caveat is if there are 5 "arn values I suppose" , how to dynamically add it to "ComponentArn":"arn"
    - ComponentArn:"arn" as I need to also include ComponentArn key in front right. So if arn value is 7, [arn1,arn2,arn3,arn4,arn5,arn6,arn7] , template will be like "-componentarn:arn1,-componentarn:arn2,componentarn:arn3........-componentarn:arn7] I dont think it will be possible with this method ? correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @SaptoBanerjee Unfortunately, there is no such functionality in CFN. You could maybe construct a custom macro which would perform transformations of your templates.